# Does anybody know how to reset authentication on gitlens extension in Visual Studio Code

Tags: linux, error-handling, editor, text-editor

**Problem:**

After `authenticating` and chosing remember `password` for `key passhrase` I can't log in to my `git repo` through `Visual Studio Code`. It gives me this error:

```
> git push origin master:master
Pass a valid window to KWallet::Wallet::openWallet().
Pass a valid window to KWallet::Wallet::openWallet().
Pass a valid window to KWallet::Wallet::openWallet().
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

[image]

My system is:

```
[13:32:47][root] ~ ~↓↓$↓↓ cat /etc/os-release                                                                                                               
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"                                                                                                                  
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"                                                                                                                                     
VERSION_ID="9"                                                                                                                                              
VERSION="9 (stretch)"                                                                                                                                       
ID=debian                                                                                                                                                   
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"                                                                                                                          
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"                                                                                                                
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

I'm using KDE.

---

Visual Studio Code is:

```
Version: 1.34.0
Commit: a622c65b2c713c890fcf4fbf07cf34049d5fe758
Date: 2019-05-15T21:55:35.507Z
Electron: 3.1.8
Chrome: 66.0.3359.181
Node.js: 10.2.0
V8: 6.6.346.32
OS: Linux x64 4.9.0-9-amd64
```

I have this function in my `.bashrc` file:

```
258 [[ $- == *i* ]] && echo "Interactive"
259 if [[ $? == 0 ]]
260 then
261     if [ -z "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ]
262     then
263         choice=""
264         printf "%s:" "Do you wish to set the ssh key now (Y/n):"
265         read choice
266         if [[ "$choice" == "Y" || "$choice" == "y" ]]
267         then
268             eval `ssh-agent`
269             ssh-add
270         fi
271     fi
272 fi
```

And it asked me if I wanted "yes or no" like in the function so the connection was using an interactive shell when it tried to authenticate me. Then it asked me for the key-passhrace.

**QUESTION:**

I need to reset something but I don't know what and google gives me nothing.

Do you know what to do to fix this?

I tried to connect with `git` command from the command line and it works so `keys` are all ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer after a little more digging.

run this in a terminal:

```
kwalletmanager5
```

On my system `kwalletmanager5` opens and goes straight to the `systemtray` immediately after its startet.

From there you can find your saved passwords and delete them.